# How to make a generic/template function in Delphi

Tags: delphi, templates, delphi-xe2

Hi I need some help in creating a template function (as they are known in c++ if I'm correct). I'm using Delphi XE2, and I'm writing a database application using an MS Access database.

The problem is that there is a lot of functions that I write that does the same thing on different tables. So I thought that I can create template functions and then just use different parameters for the different tables.

For example, there is the `Locate` function that locates a specific record in a table or query. Now I would like to make a template function of this but I do not know how to do this.

I want to put the function in the public section of my datamodule, so I was thinking in the line of this

```
function find(tableName: TADOTable, fieldName: String, fieldValue: String):Boolean
```

Then...

```
function TDataModule.find(tableName: TADOTable, fieldName: String, fieldValue:String): Boolean;
var SearchOptions : TLocateOptions;
 begin
  SearchOptions := [loCaseInsensitive]; 
  find := DataModule.tableName.Locate('fieldName', fieldValue, SearchOptions);
 end;
```

But this do not want compile...

It there any way to make some kind of template function where I can pass any table as a parameter or would it be beter to create a class for every single table, with getter and setter functions?

Comment: Nothing generic here. Do you mean `function TDataModule.find(tableName: TADOTable; fieldName: String; fieldValue:String): Boolean;`? Note the semicolons rather than commas.

Comment: Why do you use semicolons rather then a comma? It was what I wanted, thanks

Comment: yes, it is not "generics". But just change `find := DataModule.tableName.Locate` to  `TableName.Locate`. have to say, you should rename `tableName` parameter to `table` for ex., because it is not its name, it is `TADOTable` object. also use `result := ` instead of `find  := `

Comment: What punctuation you *want* to use is irrelevant. You have to use what the language allows. And here that means semi-colons.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the comma and semicolon difference. And I agree, I should rather use table instead of table name. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function TDataModule2.LocateData(AADOTable: String; AKeyFields: String; 
  AKeyValues: Variant; Options: TLocateOptions): Boolean;
var
  oComp: TComponent;
begin
  Result := False;
  oComp := FindComponent(AADOTable);
  if (oComp is TADOTable) and (oComp as TADOTable).Active then
    Result := (oComp as TADOTable).Locate(AKeyFields, AKeyValues, Options);
end;
```

Comment: In other words you don't need generics when polymorphism is enough!  Why not just have `ADOTable:TADOTable` as a parameter?

Comment: Yes, you can use the TADOTable but this is just an example. Why using the LocateData. if I set <TADOTable>.Locate('MyField','MyValue',[]) or TDataModule2.LocateData(<TADOTable>, 'MyField','MyValue',[]) on the form i prefer to use to set <TADOTable>.Locate